# stream sound comparasion in android

Tags: android, audio, stream, comparison

Im trying to create an App and I need stream sound comparison. something like these new camera apps that detects cheese and takes the picture.
what am I trying to do , is that user records an audio (its ok) and runs the service, then whenever phone heard sound like that,It would do something.

I have already see
[speech recognition and sound comparation witth musicg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665909/speech-recognition-and-sound-comparation-witth-musicg)
 and [Compare two sound in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213090/compare-two-sound-in-android)
in both , the sound should be recorded and saved somewhere.

any Ideas ?!
source code ?!

tnx